# Taylor Series Remainder, gradient methods

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, taylor-expansion, gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand a proof that taking a small enough step along the descent direction decreases the objective function in gradient descent methods.

Given a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
with $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$ and the half-line of vectors:

$\{x_\alpha = x - \alpha \nabla f(X): \alpha > 0 \} $

It says that a first-order Taylor approximation around x yields:

$\begin{align}f(x_{\alpha}) &= f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(x_\alpha - x) + o(||x_\alpha - x||) \\
&= f(x) - \alpha ||\nabla f(x)||^2 + o(\alpha ||\nabla f(x)||) \\
&= f(x) - \alpha ||\nabla f(x)||^2 + o(\alpha)
\end{align}
$

However it is quite unclear to me what the term $o(||x_\alpha - x||)$ exactly means, where its from and why it can be simplified to $o(\alpha)$ in the last step.

Comment: The $o(\|x_\alpha-x\|)$ means that the remaining terms are higher powers of $\|x_\alpha-x\|$ so that when $\alpha$ is sufficiently small, this term is dominated by $\|x_\alpha-x\|$.  Since $\|\nabla f(x)\|$ is a constant in this problem and $o$ notation only cares about the growth rate (not constants), the constant can be removed in the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling the [multivariate Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions), we find that the error in a Taylor expansion (up to degree $1$) is 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n h_i(x_\alpha)((x_\alpha)_i-\alpha_i)
$$
where $h_i(x_\alpha)$ approaches zero as $x_\alpha$ approaches $x$.  In this case, we get that the error is bounded from above by
$$
\|x_\alpha-x\|\sum_{i=1}^nh_i(x_\alpha).
$$

Now, consider the relationship between this and $C\|x_\alpha-x\|$ for any constant $C$.  Since the $h_i$'s approach zero, for any $C$ you choose, with $\alpha$ sufficiently small, the entire error is dominated by $C\|x_\alpha-x\|$.  This is what the little-oh notation means here: In terms of $\alpha$, when $\alpha$ gets small, the error is going to zero faster than $\|x_\alpha-x\|$ does.  You can think of this as saying that the error is significantly smaller than $\|x_\alpha-x\|$.

The little-oh notation is about growth rates, so it doesn't depend on constants.  In this problem, $\|\nabla f(x)\|$ is really just a constant since $x$ is fixed.  Therefore, this factor can be absorbed into the little-oh.

Therefore, the last line is saying that 
$f(x_\alpha)$ is equal to $f(x)-\alpha\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$ plus an error term.  The error term is $o(\alpha)$, meaning that it goes to zero faster than $\alpha$ does.  Therefore, for $\alpha$ sufficiently small, ehe error term is significantly smaller than $\alpha\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$.